# CodeIgniter active record, Add IF statement in ->select() function

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this query:

```
$this->db->select("
    IF(predicts.predict_owner = votes.vote_user_id , IF(judges.judge_did_accept = 1 , True , False) , 'NotExists' )" , 'user_judgement');
```

I get syntax error on

```
  `'NotExists'` )
```

If I run the query directly inside the database, it works fine...
Is there any way to prevent CI to add the sign `  automatically?

Thanks

Comment: What are you passing there as a second parameter?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can call the select method with FALSE as the last parameter, like this

```
$this->db->select("IF(predicts.predict_owner = votes.vote_user_id , IF(judges.judge_did_accept = 1 , True , False) , 'NotExists' ),'user_judgement'",false);
```

That will prevent CI to add the `

From [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

PS: I see you call select with the second param as "user_judgement", I'm not sure what that should be doing, it's not the cay CI wants you to use Active Record